# Which is the correct method for initialising the moment with Vue?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, momentjs, vuex

I am using a Vuex store but I think this question would still apply if you are not using a store.

According to the Vue documentation, the correct way to set multiple properties on an object is to use `Object.assign()` and create a new object.

```
export default {
    state: { 
        eventDateMoment : {}  
    },
    mutations : { 
        initialiseDate(state, payload) {
            state.eventDateMoment = Object.assign({}, state.eventDateMoment, moment(payload.eventDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }      
    }
}
```

As far as I can see though, that copies only the fields.  It does not copy the methods.  So how do I store an object that includes methods?

I have found two approaches that appear to work, but I don't trust them, since they contravene the rules laid out in the Vue documentation.  I doubt they would behave as a responsive property should under all circumstances.

The first approach is to simply reassign the property in the mutator.

```
mutations : { 
    initialiseDate(state, payload) {
        state.eventDateMoment = moment(payload.eventDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
    }
}
```

The second approach is to set the initial value of the store to a moment object, then use `Object.assign` to merge in the new properties, without creating a new object.

```
export default {
    state: { 
        eventDateMoment : moment()  
    },
    mutations : { 
        initialiseDate(state, payload) {
            state.eventDateMoment = Object.assign(state.eventDateMoment, moment(payload.eventDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, neither of these are acceptable.  So, what's the correct way to store an object with methods?

Comment: Is it possible that you could create a class and then assign a new object to your store state?

Answer (score 0):

Your secound approach looks good, it makes sure that all major methods and properties of a moment instance are present and overrides them in the mutation, thats ok.
Don't over estimate the `Object.assign`-method, the `Vue.set` method is more advised as you can see in the documentation here [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules) setting an initial moment object in the state does use the `Vue.set` method under the hood.